# Why can't I cd to my home directory?

Tags: linux, terminal

I am user `anupam` and when `grep anupam /etc/passwd`:

```
anupam:x:1001:1001::/home/anupam:/bin/sh
```

I have found my home directory is `/home/anupam` but when I tried `cd /home/anupam`:

```
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/anupam
```

What is the actual reason and problem behind this?

Comment: What's the output of `namei -l /home/anupam`?

Comment: it says :  `f: /home/anupam
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
                     anupam - No such file or directory`

Comment: That means `/home` exists but `/home/anupam` does not. You may need to use root (or sudo) to `mkdir /home/anupam` and then `chown 1001:1001 /home/anupam`